# Using ArcGIS API for JavaScript 3,X Directions widget?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, direction

Can I select only one country in the Directions widget in ArcGIS API for JavaScript 3,X?

For example: I want to select only UK. If the user writes Spain he will find nothing.